# App crash notification shown, but app still running?

Tags: android, crash, android-logcat

What could be the problem ? sometimes app crashes visibly but rest of the time it is not visible to user, stil often comes a notification in the very beginning that it's been crashed. No crash report in logcat, please help!

```
9243/? E/Zygote: v2
    06-22 06:27:57.187 29243-29243/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10299
    06-22 06:27:57.187 29243-29243/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
    06-22 06:27:57.188 29243-29243/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
    06-22 06:27:57.189 29243-29243/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0007, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
    06-22 06:27:57.191 29243-29243/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap 
    06-22 06:27:57.197 29243-29243/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
    06-22 06:27:57.226 29243-29243/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaKeyStore is not enabled: cannot add TimaSignature Service and generateKeyPair Service
    06-22 06:27:57.303 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/ActivityThread: Application com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
    06-22 06:27:57.321 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
    06-22 06:27:58.284 29243-29250/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/art: Debugger is active
    06-22 06:27:58.322 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: Debugger has connected
    06-22 06:27:58.322 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    06-22 06:27:58.523 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    06-22 06:27:58.723 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    06-22 06:27:58.923 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    06-22 06:27:59.124 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    06-22 06:27:59.324 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    06-22 06:27:59.525 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    06-22 06:27:59.725 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: debugger has settled (1379)
    06-22 06:28:00.022 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap-2/lib/arm
    06-22 06:28:00.171 29243-29309/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
    06-22 06:28:00.189 29243-29309/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
    06-22 06:28:00.278 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying listeners about user ( eQXuTRJZckU59DCfUzintuDJ3cD2 ).
    06-22 06:28:00.318 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.flags:2 and remote module com.google.android.gms.flags:0
    06-22 06:28:00.318 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.flags
    06-22 06:28:00.323 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
    06-22 06:28:00.351 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.
    06-22 06:28:00.358 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.crash:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.crash:7
    06-22 06:28:00.358 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.crash, version >= 7
    06-22 06:28:00.398 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000f/n/armeabi-v7a
    06-22 06:28:00.398 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000f/n/armeabi
    06-22 06:28:00.423 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/FirebaseCrashApiImpl: FirebaseCrashApiImpl created by ClassLoader q[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000f/DynamiteModulesC_GmsCore_prodmnc_xxhdpi_release.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000f/n/armeabi-v7a, /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000f/n/armeabi, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]]
    06-22 06:28:00.443 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.flags:2 and remote module com.google.android.gms.flags:0
    06-22 06:28:00.443 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.flags
    06-22 06:28:00.465 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.
    06-22 06:28:00.513 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/FirebaseCrashApiImpl: FirebaseCrash reporting API initialized
    06-22 06:28:00.567 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 10240
    06-22 06:28:00.567 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
    06-22 06:28:00.592 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                                                     adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap
    06-22 06:28:00.593 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
    06-22 06:28:00.650 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/FirebaseCrash: FirebaseCrash reporting initialized com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnq@e314d5
    06-22 06:28:00.651 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
    06-22 06:28:00.653 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
    06-22 06:28:00.966 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
    06-22 06:28:00.968 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = com.samsung.android.hardware.context.ISemContextService$Stub$Proxy@b6f9862
    06-22 06:28:00.970 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.gesture.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@3b2d8ae
    06-22 06:28:00.970 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.gesture.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@3b2d8ae
    06-22 06:28:01.018 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/zzai: Making Creator dynamically
    06-22 06:28:01.120 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000e/n/armeabi
    06-22 06:28:01.252 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 10240000
    06-22 06:28:01.262 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 11055438
    06-22 06:28:01.521 29243-29248/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=30KB
    06-22 06:28:01.522 29243-29248/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/art: After code cache collection, code=28KB, data=30KB
    06-22 06:28:01.522 29243-29248/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
    06-22 06:28:01.927 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
    06-22 06:28:01.928 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = com.samsung.android.hardware.context.ISemContextService$Stub$Proxy@442080a
    06-22 06:28:01.929 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.gesture.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@4ca87b
    06-22 06:28:01.929 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.gesture.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@4ca87b
    06-22 06:28:02.077 29243-29385/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/agl: copyMemory is missing from platform - proto runtime falling back to safer methods.
    06-22 06:28:02.099 29243-29347/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
    06-22 06:28:02.109 29243-29347/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled true
    06-22 06:28:02.110 29243-29347/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
    06-22 06:28:02.110 29243-29347/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: getDebugLevel 0x4f4c
    06-22 06:28:02.110 29243-29347/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-43766-263956484: SmartBonding Enabling is true, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false, DEBUG_LEVEL (1-LOW, 2-MID, 3-HIGH) is 1
    06-22 06:28:02.110 29243-29347/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-43766-263956484: SMARTBONDING_FEATURE_ENABLED is true
    06-22 06:28:02.111 29243-29347/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled true
    06-22 06:28:02.319 29243-29248/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=59KB, data=61KB
    06-22 06:28:02.319 29243-29248/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/art: After code cache collection, code=58KB, data=61KB
    06-22 06:28:02.319 29243-29248/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
    06-22 06:28:02.387 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/Choreographer: init sf_choreo_doframe   debug_Level : 0x4f4cdebug_game_running : false
    06-22 06:28:02.399 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@f88c98[LocationActivity]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=false
    06-22 06:28:02.405 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=108
    06-22 06:28:02.406 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@f88c98[LocationActivity]: setView = DecorView@69130d6[LocationActivity] touchMode=true
    06-22 06:28:02.410 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
    06-22 06:28:02.413 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.

                                                                                            [ 06-22 06:28:02.413 29243:29243 D/         ]
                                                                                            onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:eQXuTRJZckU59DCfUzintuDJ3cD2
    06-22 06:28:02.417 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@f88c98[LocationActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#1
    06-22 06:28:02.485 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@a093652[Toast]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=true
    06-22 06:28:02.490 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=109
    06-22 06:28:02.490 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@a093652[Toast]: setView = android.widget.LinearLayout{9e54d23 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} touchMode=true
    06-22 06:28:02.513 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@f88c98[LocationActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
    06-22 06:28:02.551 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@f88c98[LocationActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true -897626112} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
    06-22 06:28:02.553 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@f88c98[LocationActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true -897626112} hwInitialized=true
    06-22 06:28:02.604 29243-29427/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so
    06-22 06:28:02.635 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/AbsListView:  onsize change 
    06-22 06:28:02.644 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@a093652[Toast]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
    06-22 06:28:02.647 29243-29427/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    06-22 06:28:02.647 29243-29427/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
    06-22 06:28:02.655 29243-29427/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
    06-22 06:28:02.686 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@a093652[Toast]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[183,1593][897,1728] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true -897624064} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
    06-22 06:28:02.687 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@a093652[Toast]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true -897624064} hwInitialized=true
    06-22 06:28:02.688 29243-29427/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [714x135]-format:1
    06-22 06:28:02.717 29243-29248/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/art: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
    06-22 06:28:02.734 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
    06-22 06:28:02.829 29243-29250/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/art: Suspending all threads took: 26.724ms
    06-22 06:28:02.834 29243-29254/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.209ms
    06-22 06:28:02.839 29243-29254/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1285(72KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 18MB/30MB, paused 6.882ms total 36.673ms
    06-22 06:28:03.046 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    06-22 06:28:03.077 29243-29389/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1680]-format:2
    06-22 06:28:03.234 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@f88c98[LocationActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
    06-22 06:28:03.234 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@f88c98[LocationActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
    06-22 06:28:03.235 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@f88c98[LocationActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true -897626112}
    06-22 06:28:03.242 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
    06-22 06:28:03.247 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@a093652[Toast]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(183, 1593 - 897, 1728) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
    06-22 06:28:03.247 29243-29334/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=125
    06-22 06:28:03.251 29243-29323/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/FA: Connected to remote service
    06-22 06:28:03.254 29243-29248/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/art: Do full code cache collection, code=125KB, data=123KB
    06-22 06:28:03.257 29243-29248/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/art: After code cache collection, code=112KB, data=89KB
    06-22 06:28:03.310 29243-29346/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled true
    06-22 06:28:03.310 29243-29346/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
    06-22 06:28:03.311 29243-29346/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: getDebugLevel 0x4f4c
    06-22 06:28:03.311 29243-29346/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-43765-73175022: SmartBonding Enabling is true, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false, DEBUG_LEVEL (1-LOW, 2-MID, 3-HIGH) is 1
    06-22 06:28:03.311 29243-29346/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-43765-73175022: SMARTBONDING_FEATURE_ENABLED is true
    06-22 06:28:03.311 29243-29346/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled true
    06-22 06:28:03.693 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@f88c98[LocationActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
    06-22 06:28:03.714 29243-29248/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=121KB, data=98KB
    06-22 06:28:03.714 29243-29248/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/art: After code cache collection, code=120KB, data=98KB
    06-22 06:28:03.714 29243-29248/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
    06-22 06:28:04.170 29243-29394/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
    06-22 06:28:04.188 29243-29394/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:3
    06-22 06:28:04.189 29243-29394/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 3
    06-22 06:28:04.200 29243-29394/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000b/n/armeabi-v7a
    06-22 06:28:04.200 29243-29394/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000b/n/armeabi
    06-22 06:28:04.840 29243-29250/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/art: Suspending all threads took: 31.621ms
    06-22 06:28:05.375 29243-29250/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/art: Suspending all threads took: 64.456ms
    06-22 06:28:05.395 29243-29348/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled true
    06-22 06:28:05.395 29243-29348/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
    06-22 06:28:05.396 29243-29348/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: getDebugLevel 0x4f4c
    06-22 06:28:05.396 29243-29348/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-43767-239205877: SmartBonding Enabling is true, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false, DEBUG_LEVEL (1-LOW, 2-MID, 3-HIGH) is 1
    06-22 06:28:05.397 29243-29348/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-43767-239205877: SMARTBONDING_FEATURE_ENABLED is true
    06-22 06:28:05.397 29243-29348/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled true
    06-22 06:28:05.735 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@a093652[Toast]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#4
    06-22 06:28:05.755 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@a093652[Toast]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
    06-22 06:28:05.771 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=109
    06-22 06:28:05.815 29243-29349/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled true
    06-22 06:28:05.816 29243-29349/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
    06-22 06:28:05.816 29243-29349/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: getDebugLevel 0x4f4c
    06-22 06:28:05.816 29243-29349/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-43768-170702361: SmartBonding Enabling is true, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false, DEBUG_LEVEL (1-LOW, 2-MID, 3-HIGH) is 1
    06-22 06:28:05.817 29243-29349/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-43768-170702361: SMARTBONDING_FEATURE_ENABLED is true
    06-22 06:28:05.817 29243-29349/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled true
    06-22 06:28:05.845 29243-29347/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled true
    06-22 06:28:05.847 29243-29346/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled true
    06-22 06:28:05.848 29243-29346/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
    06-22 06:28:05.848 29243-29346/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: getDebugLevel 0x4f4c
    06-22 06:28:05.848 29243-29346/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-43765-71932629: SmartBonding Enabling is true, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false, DEBUG_LEVEL (1-LOW, 2-MID, 3-HIGH) is 1
    06-22 06:28:05.849 29243-29347/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
    06-22 06:28:05.849 29243-29346/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-43765-71932629: SMARTBONDING_FEATURE_ENABLED is true
    06-22 06:28:05.849 29243-29347/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: getDebugLevel 0x4f4c
    06-22 06:28:05.849 29243-29347/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-43766-59756735: SmartBonding Enabling is true, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false, DEBUG_LEVEL (1-LOW, 2-MID, 3-HIGH) is 1
    06-22 06:28:05.849 29243-29347/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-43766-59756735: SMARTBONDING_FEATURE_ENABLED is true
    06-22 06:28:05.850 29243-29346/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled true
    06-22 06:28:05.850 29243-29347/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled true
    06-22 06:28:06.346 29243-29348/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled true
    06-22 06:28:06.347 29243-29348/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
    06-22 06:28:06.347 29243-29348/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: getDebugLevel 0x4f4c
    06-22 06:28:06.347 29243-29348/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-43767-224692563: SmartBonding Enabling is true, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false, DEBUG_LEVEL (1-LOW, 2-MID, 3-HIGH) is 1
    06-22 06:28:06.348 29243-29348/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-43767-224692563: SMARTBONDING_FEATURE_ENABLED is true
    06-22 06:28:06.348 29243-29348/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled true
    06-22 06:28:06.349 29243-29349/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled true
    06-22 06:28:06.349 29243-29349/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
    06-22 06:28:06.350 29243-29349/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: getDebugLevel 0x4f4c
    06-22 06:28:06.350 29243-29349/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-43768-249033360: SmartBonding Enabling is true, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false, DEBUG_LEVEL (1-LOW, 2-MID, 3-HIGH) is 1
    06-22 06:28:06.350 29243-29349/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-43768-249033360: SMARTBONDING_FEATURE_ENABLED is true
    06-22 06:28:06.351 29243-29349/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled true
    06-22 06:28:09.490 29243-29347/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled true
    06-22 06:28:09.490 29243-29347/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
    06-22 06:28:09.490 29243-29347/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: getDebugLevel 0x4f4c
    06-22 06:28:09.490 29243-29347/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-43766-19739220: SmartBonding Enabling is true, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false, DEBUG_LEVEL (1-LOW, 2-MID, 3-HIGH) is 1
    06-22 06:28:09.491 29243-29347/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-43766-19739220: SMARTBONDING_FEATURE_ENABLED is true
    06-22 06:28:09.491 29243-29347/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled true
    06-22 06:28:10.276 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@f88c98[LocationActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1920, 1080) ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=2
    06-22 06:28:10.428 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@f88c98[LocationActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1920,1080] newFrame=[0,0][1920,1080] result=0x21 surface={isValid=true -897626112} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
    06-22 06:28:10.449 29243-29427/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1920x1080]-format:1
    06-22 06:28:10.450 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/ViewRootImpl@f88c98[LocationActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.updateSurface() mSurface={isValid=true -897626112}
    06-22 06:28:10.470 29243-29243/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/AbsListView:  onsize change 
    06-22 06:28:10.511 29243-29389/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1920x840]-format:2
```

Comment: When the app crashed ?

Comment: At the very beginning as per the notification in the device screen.

Comment: why -1? i have described it as it has occurred.

Comment: 06-22 06:28:00.171 29243-29309/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
    06-22 06:28:00.189 29243-29309/com.javapapers.android.androidlocationmap W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

Is it this?

Comment: May be. I'm not familiar with Firebase

Comment: actually the reason was related with a foreground service not releasing the wake lock on application exit causing the crash whenever i run a new instance of the same app, finally solved!

Comment: congrats.......'